# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined in public.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

recently I am getting an error

```
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (public.js:1)
    at i (jquery.js:1)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:1)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js:1)*
```

This has worked for a long time now but I suspect a recent update causes this error.
I did not create the script myself and I am not that familiar with JS, but I am still trying to figure it out.

If I am not mistaken this is the relevant code:

```
if($("#ship-to-different-address-checkbox").get(0).checked){$("#ship-to-
different-address-
checkbox").get(0).checked=false;$(".shipping_address").addClass("dhl-
hide");$("#ship-to-different-address-checkbox").trigger("change");}
```

Comment: seems like something has changed in your HTML which is causing $("#ship-to-different-address-checkbox").get(0) to be undefined

Comment: Try reverting back to previous version or make following change in your script --        if($("#ship-to-different-address-checkbox").get(0) && $("#ship-to-different-address-checkbox").get(0).checked){$("#ship-to-
different-address-
checkbox").get(0).checked=false;$(".shipping_address").addClass("dhl-
hide");$("#ship-to-different-address-checkbox").trigger("change");}

Answer (score 0):

"The script was working properly before some changes but you can't identify which one"

There's not much information about the circumstances that cause this issue, so I'm going to assume a few scenarios to help you find a solution.

Scenario 1: Let's say that at the time the script runs the element is not available in the DOM, so when you try to access the property `checked` it fails.

Make sure you only access a property if the element is available and ready!  See ( https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ ), example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($("#ship-to-different-address-checkbox").get(0).checked) {
    $("#ship-to-different-address-checkbox").get(0).checked=false;$(".shipping_address").addClass("dhl-hide");
    $("#ship-to-different-address-checkbox").trigger("change");
  }
});
```

And why not place the  closest to the ?

Scenario 2: The element ID changed, so the selector returns undefined. Double check the ID for that element, check if the element exists and is a DOM element before trying to access the property and confirm that the selected `element` or DOM element is of the right type and have the property `checked`, example:

```
// ID should always refer to a single element,
// it's not valid to have more then one element ID in the page
// So, expect only one:
var element = $("#ship-to-different-address-checkbox")

// You should do this for any other selector/element
if (typeof element !== 'undefined' && element.is(":checkbox") && element.checked) {
    element.checked.checked = false
    // anything else
    element.trigger("change");
}
```

You can of course, put them all together, like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var element = $("#ship-to-different-address-checkbox")

  if (typeof element !== 'undefined' && element.is(":checkbox") && element.checked) {
      element.checked.checked = false
      // anything else
      element.checked.trigger("change");
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello @punkbit thank you so much for your elaborate response! I have tried applying your solution but unfortunately my skills are not good enough to get it. Would you be able to help in (in return of some reward).